# Match a User to a Role with c#

Tags: c#, csv

Im having a slight problem with this.

I have a csv file with users in the first column and the users entitlements in the second.

Here is a sample of the file:

```
 USER,           ENTITLEMENTS
 ACC_EXTRACT,   SBL/All Ins Apps
 ACC_EXTRACT,   SBL/PRC
 ACC_RECON, SBL/AccountingAdmin
 ACC_RECON, SBL/All Ins Apps
```

What i trying to do is to check which users have specific 
entitlements to which i can assign a role. 
For example, the user ACC_EXTRACT has two entitlements: SBL/All Ins Apps and SBL/PRC 
and i want to assign him role x. How do i go about reading through the file and checking which
entitlments are assigned to which user?

This is the code i have so far, but im not sure if it works or if its efficient.

```
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            users = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] split = users.Split(',');

            if (split[1].Contains("SBL/FO/Rpt") | split[1].Contains("SBL/Live Ins                Apps") | split[1].Contains("SBL/Port_Grp") | split[1].Contains("SBL/Prices") | split[1].Contains("SBL/SalesPerson"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(split[1] + " " + split[0]);
                sw.WriteLine(split[0] + " , " + "Front Office - SalesPerson");
                sw.Flush();
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your code contains at least two errors:

You read the line two times in a single loop
You use the bitwise OR (|) operator instead of the logical one (||)

```
while ((users = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] split = users.Split(',');
    if (split[1].Contains("SBL/FO/Rpt") ||
        split[1].Contains("SBL/Live Ins Apps") || 
        split[1].Contains("SBL/Port_Grp") || 
        split[1].Contains("SBL/Prices") || 
        split[1].Contains("SBL/SalesPerson"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(split[1] + " " + split[0]);
        sw.WriteLine(split[0] + " , " + "Front Office - SalesPerson");
        sw.Flush();
    }
}
```

also I will add an extension method to the string class like this:

```
   public static bool ContainsAny(this string s, params string[] values)
   {
        return values.Any(x => x.Equals(s));
   }
```

to simplify the if test in this way

```
    if (split[1].ContainsAny("SBL/FO/Rpt", "SBL/Live Ins Apps","SBL/Port_Grp",
                             "SBL/Prices","SBL/SalesPerson"))
    {
        .....
    }
```